# How to change the default functionality of onMarkerClick of onMarkerClickListener to something else

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to show a dialogbox when I tap to a marker on map. but it is not working. the thing that happens is the camera only moves to center of the screen which is the default thing. but I override the method and returned true!  why am I not getting it?

```
 @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if( (marker.getId()).equals(savedMarkerId)){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder1.setMessage("hello there!!")
                   .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                                   
                       }
                   });                         
           builder1.create();
           builder1.show();


        }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe (marker.getId()).equals(savedMarkerId) is always false, check it. Do you assign proper ids to your markers?

Comment: I removed that condition to just show a dialog when tapped on marker. Still not working /not showing the dialog

Comment: Hmm, it should definitely work then. Is there any chance, that you change your OnMarkerClickListener later, by calling setOnMarkerClickListener again in your code with different onMarkerClick method(or null OnMarkerClickListener), or you call setOnMarkerClickListener on wrong map instance?

Comment: Is this listener registered?

Answer (score 0):

builder.create() returns the Alertdialog that you want to show in the next step

```
AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
alert11.show();
```